# How to design the facebook id login process from iphone using GAE as the background server?

Tags: iphone, facebook, google-app-engine, authentication

I'm designing an iPhone/android app which needs user to login using his/her facebook account.

The app uses GAE (Google App Engine) as the background server, so the problem now is that I don't know how GAE, iPhone and Facebook authentication works.

My guess is user login FB from iPhone and will get an access_token, and then the iphone app sends the access_token to GAE so that GAE can recognize the user.

Is that correct? Or is there any tutorial about how to cooperate between these platforms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [LeanEngine](http://www.lean-engine.com/) open source project. It was designed to do exactly what you are trying to do - login from a mobile device to GAE with Facebook or OpenID account (and sync data between the client and GAE).
It consists of a preprogrammed GAE application and libraries for Android and iOS and if you are satisfied with the built-in functionality you really do not need to do any modifications to the server part. You can just use it as it is.

Comment: Thanks! It looks good and really provides what I need. But it seems a very new project, and the document isn't complete yet. Anyway thanks for providing such a useful information. I very look forward this project!